# Get the state of an atom, and reset it atomically

Tags: clojure, atomic

I'm writing a [Mandelbrot Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set) implementation, and to speed up finding out which points go off into infinity, I decided to try using an `ExecutorService` to check the points in parallel.

Basically the plan is:

- Calculate all the points I need to find
- Give each point to the service
- Have the service dump its results into an `Atom` wrapping a `vector` as they are produced
- Have the drawing code periodically **grab the produced results, and clear the queue**

My problem is with the last point. How can I safely grab the previous results from an atom, *and* reset it?

I thought about the simple way of just:

```
(def draw-queue-A (atom []))

(defn grab-and-clear-queue []
  (let [results @draw-queue-A]
    (reset! draw-queue-A [])
    results))
```

But this looks unsafe. If something is added between the dereference and the `reset!`, it will be lost.

The atrocious abomination I've settled on at the moment is:

```
(defn grab-and-clear-queue []
  (let [results (atom [])]
    (swap! draw-queue-A
           (fn [res] (reset! results res)
                     []))
    results))
```

But using an atom just to retrieve the results seems ridiculous.

How can I sanely retrieve the contents of an atom, *and* reset it without potentially losing any results?

Comment: Someone want to comment on why this was downvoted? That's just rude and unhelpful.

Comment: I agree it is rude. I don't know who/why, but I have noticed that some troll will frequently downvote questions and/or answers that are not considered "pure" enough.

Comment: Yes, @carcigenicate, I have the same concern that valid information is being supressed. Revoted!  P.S. Don't forget to check the "problem solved" if you think it is warranted!  The "infidels" must stick together!

Comment: Is there a reason you want to completely reset the queue? I'd probably use a [PersistentQueue](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentQueue.java) and pop off one item at a time.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Because the results are being given to the `draw` function of the `quil` library (basically Processing). Since each draw/update cycle has shown to be quite expensive, I'd like to draw as many points as possible each cycle. If there are 1700*2500 (ish) pixels on my screen, it would take that many draw/update cycles to render one frame.

Comment: I definitely agree that popping one point per draw call would be the Wrong Thing. OTOH, one atom transaction per redraw frame is by no means a necessity -- if you look at the [ants demo](https://gist.github.com/spacemanaki/1093917) from the early days of Clojure, it provides an idea of just how cheap reference-type transactions are.

Comment: BTW, [`deref-reset!`](https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1454) is very much what you're looking for here.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out the demo. And yes! That's exactly what I'm looking for. The fact that its' been prescreen and is of critical priority is encouraging.

Comment: I assume you are talking about me, @AlanThompson. I often do downvote your answers; as I have mentioned to you, one reason I do this is because they often depend on the `tupelo` library I have never seen anyone but you use. This makes it more difficult to use your answers: I find them unhelpful. When I think you have made a good answer, I upvote it. As for this question itself: it is obviously silly to assume that all downvotes on a tag are by one person (whether you meant me or not). I hadn't seen this question until now, and it looks like a good one to me, so I've upvoted it.

Comment: @amalloy I have to be honest with you, you were the person I expected to have downvoted it. You hadn't commented/answered on any of my posts since that one time months ago where I disagreed with your answer to one of my questions, and figured you had held a grudge. I apologize for making an obviously poor assumption. Thanks for the support.

Comment: @Carcigenicate For your peace of mind, I just looked through your last 30 questions/answers on the [clojure] tag, and found I'd upvoted 6 times, downvoted 0 times, and 24 times not voted. I recognize you from [haskell] as well, but evidently have not voted on any of your recent posts at all. I remember disagreeing with you on occasion, but it seems nothing inaccurate or unhelpful enough to be worth a downvote.

Comment: @amalloy OK, thanks. Good to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple answer is to use a Clojure `ref` instead of an `atom`. It allows you to lock the value for more than a single function invocation (unlike `swap`):

```
(ns tst.clj.core
  (:use clj.core clojure.test tupelo.test)
  (:require [tupelo.core :as t] ))
(t/refer-tupelo)
(t/print-versions)

(def results (ref []))
(future
  (doseq [i (range 10)]
    (dosync
      (Thread/sleep 20)
      (alter results t/append i))))

(defn get-and-clear []
  (dosync
    (let [curr-results @results]
      (ref-set results [])
      curr-results)))

(doseq [i (range 10)]
  (Thread/sleep 50)
  (spyx (get-and-clear)))
```

with results:

```
-------------------------------------
   Clojure 1.8.0    Java 1.8.0_111
-------------------------------------
(get-and-clear) => [0 1]
(get-and-clear) => [2 3]
(get-and-clear) => [4]
(get-and-clear) => [5 6]
(get-and-clear) => [7]
(get-and-clear) => [8 9]
(get-and-clear) => []
(get-and-clear) => []
(get-and-clear) => []
(get-and-clear) => []
```

Other options would include using a queue from either `clojure.core.async` or [a simple Java thread-safe queue.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)

Depending on the format of your problem, you could also make use of [a Python-style generator function as described here.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/157827/generate-a-deck-of-cards-in-clojure-clojurescript#42801711)

Comment: Hmm. Well that certainly is cleaner! I was trying to avoid refs until I *really* needed them, but maybe this is the time to give them a try. Thanks. I'm going to leave this open for a day just to see if there are any other ideas.

Comment: Actually, on second thought, with the inclusion of the options at the end, I think this probably gives all the main options. Thank again.

Comment: Sounds like you should take these persistent downvotes as a signal encouraging you to improve, @AlanThompson, and not as some persecution conspiracy. Evidently I am not the only one who finds some of your answers unhelpful. This one I upvoted, because the uses of tupelo are (although still annoying and distracting) incidental: the core of the algorithm depends only on stuff in clojure.core, and is well explained.

Comment: Just poking fun at the "holier than thou" zealots (or "purer than thou" zealots?) who can't tolerate working code different from what they write.

Answer (score 7):

There is currently a [JIRA ticket](https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1454) dealing with this very request.  In the meantime, this does what you want, and is similar to what's in the patch, though I only browsed the code:

```
(defn reset-return-old!
  [atm new-value]
  (let [old-value @atm]
    (if (compare-and-set! atm old-value new-value)
      (do
        (.notifyWatches atm old-value new-value)
        old-value)
      (recur atm new-value))))
```

We rely on the CAS semantics, just as [`swap!`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Atom.java#L33) does.  We effectively spin to guarantee that we were not interrupted between the read and the CAS (although I suppose this still falls prey to the [ABA problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem), but I think in this context that's not important).

I'm notifying watches above -- if you have none, for your purposes, you can eliminate it and the `do` block to simplify further.

Comment: Neat. I might have to add this to my personal library while I wait for the official implementation to be released. Thank you.